# racket - how to use the elements of a list as a procedure (function)

Tags: function, scheme, racket, symbols, quote

I have a list that contains the "names" of some functions (for example `'(+ - *)`)

I want to use that list to call the functions

```
(define list_of_names_of_functions '(+ - *))

(define sum (car list_of_names_of_functions))

(sum 2 3)
```

However, sum is a list, so can't be used as a procedure.

How should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, using `eval` is not the right answer to this: it 'works' but it opens the way to horrors.

If you have a symbol like `+` and you want to get its dynamic value then the Racket approach to doing this is to use [namespaces](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html?q=namespaces#%28part._namespaces%29).  A namespace is really a machine which turns symbols into values in the same way that `eval` does, but that's *all* it does, unlike `eval`.  Unfortunately I don't understand namespaces very well, but this will work:

```
(define-namespace-anchor nsa)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace nsa))

(define (module-symbol-value s (in ns))
  (namespace-variable-value s #t #f in))
```

Then

```
(define function-names '(+ - / *))
(define sum (module-symbol-value (first function-names)))
```

And now

```
> (sum 1 2 3)
6
> (eq? sum +)
#t
>
```

The problem with this approach is that it's leaky: if you have something like this:

```
(module msv racket
  (provide module-symbol-value)

  (define-namespace-anchor nsa)
  (define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace nsa))

  (define secret "secret")
  
  (define (module-symbol-value s (in ns))
    (namespace-variable-value s #t #f in)))

(require 'msv)

(define oops (module-symbol-value 'secret))
```

Now `oops` is `secret`.  A way around this is to use `make-base-namespace` to get a namespace which is equivalent to `racket/base`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `list_of_names_of_functions` has symbol representation and not the actual function. you should perhaps make an alist with name and function like this:

```
(define ops `((+ . ,+) (- . ,-) (* . ,*)))
```

If you evaluate `ops` you'll see something like:

```
((+ . #<procedure:+>) 
 (- . #<procedure:->) 
 (* . #<procedure:*>))
```

There is no standard on how a function/procedure object should be represented, but it is expected that that value can be applied as any other function:

```
((cdar ops) 1 2) ; ==> 3
```

Thus you can search for `+` using:

```
(assq '+ ops)
; ==> (+ . #<procedure:+>)
(assq '/ ops)
; ==> #f
```

Thus if the result is truthy the `cdr` will contain a procedure:

```
(apply (cdr (assq '+ ops)) '(1 2)) ; ==> 3
```

If you are making a special kid of `eval` then you would consider the list an environment and it can easily be added to such that you can add `/`. You can also supply anything callable so an op doesn't need to exist in the host system. eg.   `` `(square . ,(lambda (v) (* v v)) `` works as well.

Consider using the naming convention of Scheme (and Lisp). Eg. instead of `list_of_names_of_functions` it should be named `list-of-names-of-functions`

Answer (score 1):

The simple and immediate fix is to use `(define list_of_functions (`**`list`**`+ - *))`,  then with `(define sum (car list_of_functions))` it will work.

(*edit:*) This happens because `list` is a function which evaluates its argument(s) and returns the results in a list. Whereas `quote` (or `'` in front of an expression) prevents its argument from being evaluated.

`'(A B ...)` is equivalent to `(quote (A B ...))`; that `(A B ...)` thing is a list of symbols, and quote preserves it as such.

It is a list of symbols because this is how Lisp code is read, either from a source file or from the REPL, i.e. at the interpreter's prompt. Other languages have their code as strings in a source code file, and compiler is some external magic which lives and works completely outside of the language. In Lisp-like languages, code is data. Code is read from textual source code file as (i.e. strings are turned into) nested lists of symbols, and explicit `eval`, as well as implicit evaluation, is deep inside the language itself.

Thus what you had is equivalent to the list

```
(define list_of_names (list '+ '- '*))
```

which contains unevaluated *symbols*, as opposed to the list

```
(define list_of_functions (list + - *))
```

which contains their *values*, which happen to be the usual built-in functions denoted by those "names".

And we can call a function, but we can't call a symbol (not in Scheme anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer, sorry.

Solution will be to use the "eval" function

```
(define list_of_names_of_functions '(+ - *))

(define sum (car list_of_names_of_functions))

((eval sum) 2 3)
```

Comment: Using `eval` is like using a nuclear weapon: it's an effective tool, but the problems associated with using it are, well, problems.